# AngularJS asynchronous assinging href to a link

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I need to update href of a link asynchronously. Let's say I've got this html:

```
<a ng-href="{{url}}" ng-click="resolveUrl()" target="_blank">click me</a>
```

And this angular controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $q) {
  $scope.url = '#';

  $scope.resolveUrl = function() {
    async().then(function(resolvedUrl){
      $scope.url = resolvedUrl;
    });
  }

  function async() {
    var deffered = $q.defer();

    setTimeout(function() {
      deffered.resolve('http://www.google.com');
    }, 1000)

    return deffered.promise;
  }
});
```

And I need the link to go to google.com even for the first time. How to synchronize the async call or how to assign the url so that the async function resolves?

[Code in plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2xkwLdxiW6CcIYOi29Vw?p=preview)

Edited:

As @Konstantin Krass pointed out I could use window.open(). But I cannot use it asynchronously because browsers will popup block the new window. So I've tried to open another window on-click (which is not blocked) and then after the promise is resolved I update the url of the opened window to google.com. Edited plunker is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ICuoovMDjhafbRqRxxmW?p=preview). Unfortunately this does not work on iPad. On iPad the page url is not updated because on iPad the tabs can't communicate with each other.
Any ideas?

Comment: so you want to generate the url on click ?

Comment: Your plunker is working properly. It resolves one second after your click. So if you want to go to google the first time and then resolve another url, just change $scope.url = www.google.com and the async function to the new one. http://plnkr.co/edit/SSnKwHKpoWCqbhISm2iq?p=preview

Comment: @KonstantinKrass yes. Problem is that I need to process some computing (generating blob pdf) and then assigning the blob url to the <a> link so that user can download it in a new tab.

Comment: Not sure how to do this with Angular, but can try to: `[1] prevent click, [2] disable clicking while process, [3] process link generation, [4] bind link, [5] remove disable, [6] javascript trigger click() event.` Could try to make it a button and style it as a link to make disable simpler.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to calculate the url and redirect to the url after the click, you could just use the native `location.href` after receiving the url.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $q) {     

  $scope.resolveUrl = function() {
    async().then(function(resolvedUrl){
      location.href= resolvedUrl; //this would open the url in the current page.
      // if you want to offer a download or move 
      // into new browser tab you can go like this: 
      // window.open(resolvedUrl);  
    });
  }

  function async() {
    var deffered = $q.defer();

    setTimeout(function() {
      deffered.resolve('http://www.google.com');
    }, 1000)

    return deffered.promise;
  }
});
```

And remove the `{{url}}` from html.

```
<a ng-click="resolveUrl()">click me</a>
```

Comment: Actually I can't use window.open() since it's blocked in some browsers (Safari on iPad). And I (or the customer..) need it to open in a new tab.

Comment: I think this can't be achieved like this, because the actual click event and the redirection to the url happens before any listener can inject a new url. To redirect afterwards or depend on the delayed url, you need to prevent the first relocation and use location or window

If you offering a download, why not try it with an iframe ?

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want : [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/lZtENlhG5mFZgNIbMmg3?p=preview)

```
   app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $q) {
  $scope.message = 'Create File';

  $scope.resolveUrl = function() {
    async().then(function(resolvedUrl){
       $scope.message  = "Download File"
      $scope.url = resolvedUrl;
    });
  }

  function async() {
    var deffered = $q.defer();

    setTimeout(function() {
      deffered.resolve('http://www.google.com');
    }, 1000)

    return deffered.promise;
  }
});
HTML:

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <a ng-href="{{url}}"  ng-click="resolveUrl()" target="_blank">{{message}}</a>
  </body>
```

Comment: I need the href to be pointing at google.com even on the first click. Your solution works only if I click on the link twice.

Comment: Ok so what should happend if user click on link before your file is ready ?

Comment: I need for the browser to wait until it is ready and then go to the prepared URL. I just can't figure out how to wait for the promise to resolve.